# access data segment from kernel space

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, virtual-memory, memory-model

I would like to be able to tell which pages in the page table belonging to a process are used as data segment.
I am using Linux kernel v 3.2 for amd64

here is what I did before and did not work:

1. accessing the data segment using `task->mm->start_data` (task is the task_struct for the target process).
2. searching through `task->mm->mmap` (linked list) and compare the start address of each `vm_area_struct` (`vm_start`) with the `task->mm->start_data`. Here I a assuming that the start of the data segment is aligned with the beginning of a page.

all this should be done within a kernel module.

Thanks.

Comment: Why isn't the execute attribute for each page a sufficient test (i.e. text pages allow execution and data pages cannot)?

Comment: I didn't assume or mention "copy"ing, so why do you lead with that assertion?  Your original question mentions just "data segments", but now you are looking for "static variables"?   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit  **BTW** "text page" (as opposed to "data page") in Linux is the same as "code page".  I probably made a mistake in assuming that you understood the meaning of "text".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research looks like passing task->mm->start_data to get_user_pages combined with kmap would do the trick.